# Capacitance on the output of a voltage converter

Tags: capacitor, dc-dc-converter

In a project I have a [TLV62065](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tlv62065) 5 to 3.3 V voltage converter. I need to take the maximum amount of current, i.e. 2 A. The maximum output capacity for the converter is 22 μF.

The suggested capacitance for my load circuit is 470 μF low-ESR. How should I separate these capacities, Cout 10 μF, and Cx 470 μF (5 x 100 μF X5R)? Is a 300 Ω, 100 MHz, 3 A ferrite bead OK?

In test project I used only a Cout of 10 μF, but when I soldered 5 x 100 μF behind the regulator, it did not work properly.

Schematic below, 3.3 V directly to the modem.

[image]

Comment: What is the load?

Comment: Can you show a schematic?

Comment: My load: The typical supply voltage of EC21 series Mini PCIe is 3.3 V. In the 2G network, the input peak current
may reach 2.7 A during the transmitting time. Therefore, the power supply must be able to provide a
rated output current of 2.7 A at least, and a bypass capacitor of no less than 470 μF with low ESR should
be used to prevent the voltage from dropping.

Comment: 1) Given what you are doing, you've simply got the wrong chip.  You need a chip that can deliver *more* than 2.7A when running--something like a TPS56325x is more suitable.  That way, if you need to buffer a peak, you can put all that cap on the *input* side rather than the output.


2) Are you really pulling 2A on 3.3V?  I seem to recall that a lot of cellular stuff needs 4.2V or more in order to hit the required transmit powers.  Normally, there are two separate inputs for that unless the hardware is boosting the 3.3V somewhere.


Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems, the first is having that much capacitance on the output of the converter will cause inrush current that probably exceeds the 2A of the converter.

The second problem is the output capacitance (greater than 22µF) will cause the phase of the control loop to go unstable.

So what to do? I would run a spice model and see what would happen if you stuck various impedances such as resistors, ferrites, or inductors in between the output capacitors to reduce the output capacitor's impedance and thus, improve control loop stability.

If a passive won't do it, you might need to switch to a DC-DC converter with a soft start (or add one to the current DC DC converter, which I have not done.)